# Change position of JavaScript object key and data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I am working on javascript object. And I want to pass data to next array in a specific sequence. like I get data like this

```
var obj = [{
  0: "Owner Name"
  1: "Mailing Address"
  2: "Situs Address"
  3: "APN"  
}]
```

And want this sequence to be like this

```
var obj = [{
  3: "APN"  
  0: "Owner Name"
  2: "Situs Address"  
  1: "Mailing Address" 
}];
```

Is it possible to do that, on bases of data? As I don't know from database sequence maybe change.
edit:  For those who are saying I should use array. I am getting data on basis of this object like,

```
 var data[{
  0:"CHANCE WILLIAM C & KATHRYN L"
  1:"P O BOX 7642 CHICO CA 95927"
  2:"LOT 4 PM 150-99/100"
  3:"040-310-086-000" }]
```

Comment: The properties in an object are not, and can not be, ordered in any way, so what you're trying to do is not possible. If you want to have a guaranteed order to the values put them in an array instead

Comment: The only way is to build another Map object by specifying keys & values in your desired order. But, why do you want to do this? Ordering of keys doesn't affect how you access the values..

Comment: @ChrisLam Actually I have to pass a specific sequence to JSPDF to generate a pdf in a specific standard format. So I have to make a specif sequence

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: You could retrieve them in order, using an array for the keys

Comment: @dev8080 that's still not guaranteed, as the 'array for the keys' will have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Object not have sorting property

*so you can do like this,*

Covert the array object arguments into individual object.then sorting with `dec` order of the key

```js
var obj = [{
  '0': "Owner Name",
  '1': "Mailing Address",
  '2': "Situs Address",
  '3': "APN" ,
}];

var array = Object.keys(obj[0]).map(function(a){
                  return ({[a]:obj[0][a]});
}) //recreate with individual object

var sorted= array.sort((a,b)=> Object.keys(b)-Object.keys(a))
 console.log(sorted) //sorted  object
 
var res = sorted.map(a=> Object.values(a)[0]) // for array

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Some how looking for this thing. Can I replace "0" th key with "2" ?

Comment: yes you can change it.That array also changed depend on your changes

Answer (score 2):

The properties in an object are not, and can not be, ordered in any way, so what you're trying to do is not possible. If you want to have a guaranteed order to the values put them in an array instead.

> For those who are saying I should use array. I am getting data on basis of this object

In this case you can use `Object.keys()` and `map()` to convert the object to an array:

```js
var data = [{
  0: "CHANCE WILLIAM C & KATHRYN L",
  1: "P O BOX 7642 CHICO CA 95927",
  2: "LOT 4 PM 150-99/100",
  3: "040-310-086-000"
}];

var arr = Object.keys(data[0]).map(function(k) {
  return data[0][k];
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys in a JavaScript object do not have any order. They will be displayed in any order and can change because order is not preserved.

If you need your data in a particular order, use an Array.

Example of an array of strings preserving order

```
var orderedItems = [
  "3: APN",
  "0: Owner Name",
  "2: Situs Address",
  "1: Mailing Address"
];
```

Comment: @Dellirium I made till array but sequence still I am getting from database. how I can change that ?

Comment: You are going to have to explain it a bit better, I do not understand what you mean @ephemeral